# Git Rebase - Log when commits are skipped

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

So when I do a git rebase git helpfully will tell me as it replays the commits onto the rebase target..

```
Applying: Dev on #1337 Started
Applying: Dev on #1337 Complete
```

The thing is though, is if Git runs into a commit that it deems a "no-op" eg a commit that has been cherrypicked into the source branch from the target branch, git will just skip the commit. Is there a way to get Git to tell me that it dropped/skipped that commit?

I thought maybe rebase.missingCommitsCheck would do this but after testing, it does not.

Comment: It would be really nice if it did this, either because of a flag or even by default (I think "by default" would be best), but alas, it doesn't. You can check ahead of time using `git cherry` or `git log --left-right --cherry-mark`, but this is pretty tricky to do and to understand.